# add new value to JSON files

Tags: node.js, json

Can you tell me how to add new value to JSON files, if it can be taken from this file?
I have a lot of JSON files and they are missing one value ("id:"). The good news is that these files have the value "name:" which contains text and numbers. I could use these numbers as the "id:" (file names are also numeric and I can use the file name for the value "id:"). Here's an example of how it is

```
{
    ...,
    "name": "abcd #109956",
    ...,
  }
```

and how I need to get results

```
{
    ...,
    "id": 109956,
    "name": "abcd #109956",
    ...,
  }
```

P.S.
I can merge all these files into one JSON. If it's easier to do it with one file and add a new value everywhere, tell me how to do it
Thank you!

Comment: You can read the files into a Python dictionary, add the id key:value and write the dictionary out to a JSON file.

Comment: Python or Node.js? And what did you try so far?

Comment: with python I can merge files, but I think it is better to add using node

Comment: Can you get all JSON objects into one array

Comment: "*I think it is better to add using node*" Better *how*, exactly? Both languages include extremely robust facilities for parsing, working with, and generating standards-compliant JSON data. It's not clear how exactly you reached this conclusion unless there's project-specific requirements you haven't included context for.

Comment: @esqew based only on the fact that JSON is a native node js standard. No requirements for the project, just to get files with "id:" in the output. I'm sorry if I'm not expressing myself correctly, I'm quite new at this.

Comment: @GimhanRanasinghe Thank you so much! I used your code, merging all the files into one JSON and substituting it as an array. It turned out to be just what I needed! `const data = require('./file.json');
const arr = Object.values(data);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to add id to your JSON objects you can do it as follows. (If you can take all those objects into one array.)

```js
const arr = [
  {
    name: "abcd #109956",
  },
  {
    name: "abc #109957",
  },
  {
    name: "abc #109958",
  },
];

arr.forEach((element) => {
  element.id = parseInt(element.name.split("#")[1]);
});

console.log(arr);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[
  { name: 'abcd #109956', id: 109956 },
  { name: 'abc #109957', id: 109957 },
  { name: 'abc #109958', id: 109958 }
]
```

Hope this will help you to solve your issue.

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! I see your point, it hadn't occurred to me. Of course it would be quite difficult for me to create an array of all objects from all JSON files in the directory. I'll be looking for examples. Thanks again!